# SQLite не пишет в базу primary key

Tags: pdo, php_pdo, php, sqlite3

eventid не вписывается в бд. Эко выводит его строки но там пусто. Что я пропустил подкажите пожалуйста.

```
try{
if (!file_exists("testgb")){
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:testgb');
    $db->exec("CREATE TABLE guestbook (eventid INTEGER PRIVATE KEY,name VARCHAR(55), message TEXT, date DATETIME)");
}
$db = new PDO('sqlite:testgb');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->exec("INSERT INTO guestbook (name, message, date) VALUES ('KIRILL', 'Hello!!', date('now'))");
$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM guestbook");
foreach ($res as $row){
    echo $row['eventid']."<br>";
    echo $row['name']."<br>";
    echo $row['message']."<br>";
    echo $row['date']."<br>";
    echo "<hr>";
}
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Да именно PRIMARY и должен быть... Блин какая глупая ошибка. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
   $db->exec("CREATE TABLE guestbook (eventid INTEGER PRIVATE KEY,name VARCHAR(55), message TEXT, date DATETIME)")
```

поясните что значит PRIVATE KEY ?? может вы хотели указать PRIMARY KEY